# Manifest file with Mono/MonoDevelop in order to run C# apps in Administrator

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, manifest, administrator

I have created a little C# apps with MonoDevelop that needs Administrator privileges. 
I know that it's possible to force running as administrator with a manifest file embedded with:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

This work with Visual Studio, nevertheless I use mono + MonoDevelop . 
Do you know how doing this in MonoDevelop please?

Answer (score 0):

That manifest only works for Windows (where you can use .NET Framework), so I don't see its significant usage for Mono.

But if your test shows this issue and you have a test sample available, you can create a bug report so that Mono guys can track it,

http://www.mono-project.com/Bugs

Comment: I have developped my programm with MonoDevelopp+GTK in order to use GTK#. Nevertheless i need to force to run my apps as Administrator. My programm will only run on Windows, because it's for patching a Windows Programm !

Comment: First use a tool to view if any manifest is embedded,http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2007/07/10/manifest-view-1-0.aspx. If not, then you can use an external manifest file, instead of embedding it.

Comment: Wow ! Thanks a lot my friend for your tool ! So, my EXE has a manifest ! But.....how modify him with MonoDevelop ? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Well use vs to create a project and embed a manifest. Then compare the project files and see if you can modify the project file directly. I do not think you can do it in MonoDevelop.

Comment: But my EXE is created with monodevelop, and i have manifest embedded on ! So i think it's during the compilation, ! Bu how modifyng him monoDevelop ?